# Vue - How to convert the entire project to dark mode by clicking a button?

Tags: vue.js, vue-props, darkmode

I have a Vue project and I have more than 50 components now, I want to prepare a dark mode for the entire project and I want to control the Mode type from a button on my navbar. I made a test version so I figured how to active and deactive classes but I don't know how to do that for the entire project by clicking a single button or check a checkbox. Here is my test;

```
<div class="container-main" :class="{'background-dark' : darkMode }">
      <!-- Enable Dark Mode -->
      <div>
        <label class="form-switch">
          <input type="checkbox" class="switch switch-md" v-model="darkMode" />
        </label>
        <label">Enable Dark Mode</label>
      </div>  
</div>

<style scoped>
  .background-dark {
    background-color: black;
  }
</style>
```

When the switch is checked, darkMode variable turns to true and the class gets active, so my background color turns to black. My question is, I will create the dark mode version of the CSS file I use right now and I want this control to be in the navbar, how can a button or switch control the entire components' css classes in a project. If I need to use props, how do I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you thought about using the `data-theme="..."` attribute? [Here is an article](https://dev.to/wendell_adriel/working-with-multiple-css-themes-5aej) about it.

Comment: I'll check it and let you know. Thanks.